# SMPlayer doesn't work with VDPAU?

Tags: video, mplayer, vdpau, smplayer

I recently bought a Nvidia GT 440, and installed the proprietary `nvidia-experimental-310` driver.

Every player seems to be working alright with VDPAU, except Mplayer frontends like SMPlayer.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If it actually works with mplayer:

```
mplayer -vo vdpau -vc ffh264vdpau somefile.mkv
```

in SMPlayer, it should be as simple as setting it to use vdpau in **Options / Preferences / General / Video**. Set the **Output driver** `vdpau` (it should be there in the drop-down list in a recent enough version, without the need to use the **User defined** setting).

How did you install the proprietary drivers and are you sure the required libraries for vdpau are installed?

Comment: Didn't work with mplayer, gave me this output: http://pastebin.com/0NRhFV43

I installed via apt-get install nvidia-experimental-310. Which are the libs required for vdpau? I'm pretty sure they're installed, because VLC works fine with vdpau.

Comment: If I take the "-vc ffh264vdpau" part of the command, it works fine.

Comment: @GabrielHuwe Have you also monitored CPU usage (should be very low, like 0-10 %) while VLC is playing a video to be sure, that it is really working? I would also try installing **nvidia-current** drivers from **ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates** instead of the experimental ones. If you remove the **-vc**, then it won't use vdpau properly anyway.

Comment: no, it uses 15%~30%. I am compiling a newer version of mplayer2 right now, just to test.

Comment: I can manage to make VDPAU working using CLI but not with SMPlayer, any thoughts??